# the view returns a list with a dict in it, instead of the dict itself in django api view

Tags: python-3.x, api, django-rest-framework, django-views

an api viewset returns a list, which helds a dict, yet i dont need it to be inside a list

the response:

```
[
    {
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": "",
        "username": "foo",
        "bio": null,
        "email": "foo@oo.oo",
        "role": "moderator"
    }
]
```

it should be

```
{
"first_name": "string",
"last_name": "string",
"username": "string",
"bio": "string",
"email": "string",
"role": "user"
}
```

views.py

```
class  UsernameViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    pagination_class = None
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(viewsets.ModelViewSet, self).list(request, *args, **kwargs) # call the original 'list'
        # response.data = {response.data} # customize the response data
        print(response.data)

        print(response.data[0])
        return response# return response with this custom representatio
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        username = self.kwargs.get('username', None)
        if username:
            queryset = User.objects.filter(username=username)
            print(username)
        return queryset
```

response.data[0] prints out
`OrderedDict([('first_name', ''), ('last_name', ''), ('username', 'foo'), ('bio', None), ('email', 'foo@oo.oo'), ('role', 'moderator')])`

which is what i need, ig
if i return response.data[0] it shows an error:
Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'collections.OrderedDict'>`

serializers.py:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = 'first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'bio', 'email', 'role'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add import

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
```

and

```
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(viewsets.ModelViewSet, self).list(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return Response(data=response.data[0])
```

or write a custom `list` method which makes more sense

```
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset[0])
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Though have in mind that's a terrible idea. You are using a `list` method and expect it not to return a `list`.

You are filtering queryset by `username`. So you should use `retrieve` method and set `lookup_field` to `username`. Then, `retrieve` method would return a single dict.

In the current approach you'd sometimes get a dict (when `username` passed) and sometimes a list, which is not the best idea.

Comment: OMG THANK YOU THE COMMENT ABOUT USING LOOKUP_FIELD FIXED EVERYTHING< DIDNT EVEN NEED THIS VIEW AND ANOTHER ROUTE